# Best way to add Disqus comments to a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, disqus

Is there anything better than the [Disqus Ruby Gem](http://github.com/norman/disqus)? Perhaps something geared specifically towards Rails?

(The Disqus gem might be the best option, I just haven't been able to find much color one way or the other).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Ruby gem's helper just embeds Disqus' native Javascript, which is bad because it loads the Disqus comments synchronously.

Rather than make users wait, I did some hacking and got the comments to load asynchronously. [Check out my blog post on the subject.](http://www.pleaselistencarefully.com/2009/10/how-to-load-disqus-comments.html)

Comment: your link doesn't work. There is application error there

Comment: There is a problem to the given link.

Comment: Try here: https://web.archive.org/web/20100819002445/http://www.pleaselistencarefully.com/2009/10/how-to-load-disqus-comments.html

Answer (score 7):

You can always just sign up for an account for your site and stick their generic javascript into your page where you want it:

http://disqus.com/websites/

Answer (score 3):

Since Feb 2010 The disqus javascript will load asynchronously.

http://blog.disqus.com/post/397517128/making-disqus-faster

> Nothing will be waiting on Disqus to load, even if Disqus is slow to
>   respond, and the web page will load quicker.

Official embed code:
http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472097-universal-embed-code

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this myself.  There's a couple of Ruby gems, but Norman's disqus gem that you listed was the only one I could find with Rails helpers.